# Playframework: Use Scalatags instead of Twirl

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatags

I'd prefer to use the former over the latter, but am not sure how to incorporate Scalatags into the playframework.

This is my simple layout:

```
object Test
{
  import scalatags.Text.all._
  def build =
  {

    html(
      head(
        title := "Test"
      ),
      body(

        h1("This is a Triumph"),
        div(
          "Test"
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

This is how I try to render it:

```
Ok(views.Test.build.render)
```

Problem is, that I get it as a plain String, not as HTML.

Now, of course one solution would be to simply append.

```
Ok(views.Test.build.render).as("text/html")
```

but is that really the only way? (Without creating a helper method that is)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you want to be able to call `Ok(views.Test.build)`. Play is ignorant of ScalaTags so we're going to have to write *something* ourselves here.

Play uses a bit of implicit machinery to generate HTTP responses. When you call `Ok(...)` you're actually calling `apply` on the `play.api.mvc.Results` trait. Let's take a look at its signature:

```
def apply[C](content: C)(implicit writeable: Writeable[C]): Result
```

So we can see that we need an implicit `Writeable[scalatags.Text.all.Tag]`:

```
implicit def writeableOfTag(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[Tag] = {
  Writeable(tag => codec.encode("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + tag.render))
}
```

Don't forget to include a doctype declaration. ScalaTags doesn't give you one.

That call to `Writeable.apply` itself requires another implicit to determine the content type. Here is its signature:

```
def apply[A](transform: A => ByteString)(implicit ct: ContentTypeOf[A]): Writeable[A]
```

So let's write an implicit `ContentTypeOf[Tag]`:

```
implicit def contentTypeOfTag(implicit codec: Codec): ContentTypeOf[Tag] = {
  ContentTypeOf[Tag](Some(ContentTypes.HTML))
}
```

This allows us to avoid having to write `as("text/html")` explicitly *and* it includes the charset (courtesy of the implicit codec), resulting in a `Content-Type` header of `text/html; charset=utf-8`.

Putting it all together:

```
import play.api.http.{ ContentTypeOf, ContentTypes, Writeable }
import play.api.mvc.Results.Ok
import scalatags.Text.all._

def build: Tag = {
  html(
    head(
      title := "Test"
    ),
    body(

      h1("This is a Triumph"),
      div(
        "Test"
      )
    )
  )
}

implicit def contentTypeOfTag(implicit codec: Codec): ContentTypeOf[Tag] = {
  ContentTypeOf[Tag](Some(ContentTypes.HTML))
}

implicit def writeableOfTag(implicit codec: Codec): Writeable[Tag] = {
  Writeable(tag => codec.encode("<!DOCTYPE html>\n" + tag.render))
}

def foo = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(build)
}
```

You probably want to tuck those implicits somewhere convenient and then import them in your controller(s).

Comment: why twirl is the default template engine in play? scalatags seems simpler.